# Generating a large form based on model objects

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a model structure looking roughly like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product")
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField("Product", through="OrderProduct")
```

I'd like to generate a (large) form/formset that lists *all* products with for each product the 'amount' field, enabling users to place an order in one page. Like this:

```
| product name | price | etc | amount: [  ] |
| product name | price | etc | amount: [  ] |
[...]

[ Place order ]
```

So I guess, a formset of OrderProduct-based ModelForms? I've been breaking my head over how to do this. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Eventually I used manual form parsing; it seems like something like this unfortunately cannot be done easily using the Django form framework.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using ModelFormSets is a bit overhead, but you can construct a bunch of "extra" forms with built-in initial value for each product and 0 for amount. After saving you'll get only instances that have non-zero amount.

In your view:

```
formset_class = modelformset_factory(
                 OrderProduct,
                 widgets = {'product': forms.widgets.HiddenInput},
                 extra=Product.objects.count())
initial = [{'product': p.id, 'amount': 0} for p in Product.objects.all()]
formset = formset_class(data=request.POST or None, initial=initial)
...
if formset.is_valid():
  ordered_products = formset.save()
  # create your order here
```

You can access details of the product in a template through form's instance attribute:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {{ form.id }}{{ form.product }} <!-- will be hidden inputs, don't forget to add -->
  {% with product=form.instance.product %}
  {{ product.name }} | {{ product.price }} | amount: {{ form.amount }}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```